# LINQ to XML issue with converting a tree to a list

Tags: c#, linq

I need help with the following to return a set of nested lists from an xml tree:

The sample data:

```
<step>
  <sequence>
   <step>
    <type></type>
    <position>0</position>
  </step>
  <step>
    <type></type>
    <position>0</position>
  </step>
  <step>
    <type></type>
    <position>0</position>
  </step>
  <step>
    <type></type>
    <position>1</position>
  </step>
  <step>
    <type></type>
    <position>0</position>
  </step>
  <step>
    <sequence>
      <step>
        <position>0</position>
      </step>
      <step>
        <position>0</position>
      </step>
      <step>
        <position>0</position>
      </step>
      <step>
        <position>0</position>
      </step>
      <step>
        <position>0</position>
      </step>
    </sequence>
  </step>
  <step>
    <sequence>
      <step>
        <position>0</position>
      </step>
      <step>
        <position>0</position>
      </step>
      <step>
        <position>0</position>
      </step>
      <step>
        <position>0</position>
      </step>
    </sequence>
   </step>
  </sequence>  
</step>
```

My code:

```
        public List<InstructionSequence> GetSequenceFromSource(XDocument UriSource)
    {
        List<InstructionSequence> StepCollection = new List<InstructionSequence>();

        var u = from v in UriSource.Descendants("step")
                select new InstructionSequence
                {
                    step = Convert.ToInt16(v.Element("position").Value),
                    sequence = this.GetChildSequence(v)
                };

        return u.ToList<InstructionSequence>();


    }

    private List<InstructionSequence> GetChildSequence(XElement parent)
    {
        var u = (from v in parent.Descendants("step")
                 select new InstructionSequence
                 {
                     step = Convert.ToInt16(v.Element("position").Value),
                     sequence = null

                 });

        return u.ToList<InstructionSequence>();
    }
```

In one variation I can get the top level to be parsed correctly, but the child nodes are not returned - where is it going wrong?

Comment: Is this structure only two layers or can it be more?

Comment: most uses cases are for two layers, but I want to be able recursively parse as many child nodes that eventually exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the document you presented (which is a little odd) this is what you need to convert it to a `InstructionSequence`:

```
public InstructionSequence GetSequenceFromSource(XDocument UriSource)
{
    return this.GetSequenceFromSource(UriSource.Root);
}

public InstructionSequence GetSequenceFromSource(XElement step)
{
    return new InstructionSequence
    {
        step = step.Element("position") == null ? 0 : (int)step.Element("position"),
        sequence = step.Element("sequence")?.Elements("step").Select(s => this.GetSequenceFromSource(s)).ToList(),
    };
}
```

Please note that you asked for a list, but the root node of the XML is a `step` so it appears you actually only need to return a single `InstructionSequence` (which internally holds a list).

My code is recursive and will go down as far as the stack will allow.

With your source data from your question I get this result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = doc.Root
             .Descendants("sequence")
             .Descendants("step")
             .Where(e => (e.FirstNode is XElement) && (((XElement)e.FirstNode).Name != "sequence"))
             .Select(l => new InstructionSequence()
             {
                 step = Convert.ToInt32(l.Element("position").Value)
             });
```

This *sounds* like what you want, but I'm not sure. Can you provide some more details and we can work from the basis above? Maybe some sample output? You provided very little information to go off of.

### EDIT, Solution #2:

```
Func<XElement, InstructionSequence> GetChildContents = child => new InstructionSequence { step = Convert.ToInt32(child.Element("position").Value), sequence = null };

var matchItems = new List<InstructionSequence>();

var splitGroups = doc.Root
    .Descendants("step")
    .GroupBy(v => (v.FirstNode is XElement) && (((XElement)v.FirstNode).Name != "sequence"));

    var matchGroup = splitGroups.Single(e => e.Key == true);
    var remaining = splitGroups.Single(e => e.Key == false);

    matchItems.AddRange(matchGroup.Select(GetChildContents));

    matchItems.AddRange(remaining.Descendants("sequence").Descendants("step").Select(GetChildContents));
```

Is this what you were looking for? Like I said before, not a lot to go off of.
If your nodes are nested even further, I can add recursion to the above solution for you.